# Passing value between two separate MapReduce jobs

Tags: java, hadoop

I have an Hadoop program, where I need to pass a single output which is generated from first MapReduce task to a second MapReduce task.

Ex.

MapReduce -1 -> Writes double value to the hdfs (file name is similar to part-00000). 
In the second MapReduce job I want to use the double value from part-00000 file.

How can I do it. Can anyone please give some code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for first job to finish and then run second one on the output of the first. You can do it:

1) In the **Driver**:

```
 int code = firstJob.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
 if (code) {
     Job secondJob = new Job(new Configuration(), "JobChaining-Second");
     TextInputFormat.addInputPath(secondJob, outputDirOfFirstJob);
     ...
 }
```

2) Use **JobControl** and **ControlledJob**:

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/jobcontrol/JobControl.html

To use *JobControl*, start by wrapping your jobs with *ControlledJob*. Doing this is
relatively simple: you create your job like you usually would, except you also create a
*ControlledJob* that takes in your *Job* or *Configuration* as a parameter, along with a
list of its dependencies (other *ControlledJobs*). Then, you add them one-by-one to the
*JobControl* object, which handles the rest.

3) Externally (e.g. from **shell script**). Pass input/output paths as arguments.

4) Use **Apache Oozie**. You will specify your jobs in XML.

Comment: 5) http://azkaban.github.io/azkaban2/ is another way of creating DAG of workflows.